# How to split string every 3 commas that have text between them?

Tags: php

I have string like that

```
234,153,25,25,85,36,40,40,188,155,60,60
```

I want to insert this to array but like that:

```
[234,153,25,25],[85,36,40,40],[188,155,60,60]
```

I think to do a for loop on the string but how can I do it every 4 commas?

**Edit:**
I need now to count the length of the array
I try to use "**[count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)**" and "**[sizeof](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php)**" functions but they not count correctly the array. what can be the problem?

For example if the array is empty the sizeof and the count return me 1

Comment: [`explode`](http://php.net/explode), [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/array_chunk)…

Comment: have you tried anything so far? Could you add sample code?

Comment: @rudolf_franek no I dont know how to go for it

Comment: have you programmed in php anything before?

Comment: @deceze provided you with some really useful sources that actually solve your problem. Why don't you give it a try, come back with what you have tried and we take it from there? If you don't manage to complete it, it's ok we can help but put some effort on it.

Comment: @John  hope this help:- https://eval.in/1051388

Comment: Could enter the wild world of regex as well...`\d+,\d+,\d+(?:,|$)`.

Comment: I would rather use this regex, user: (\d+(,?)){4}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.First [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string using `,`

2.Then you need to use [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to get desired array

```
<?php

$string = '234,153,25,25,85,36,40,40,188,155,60,60';

$exploded_array = explode(',',$string);

$final_array = array_chunk(array_filter($exploded_array) ,4);

print_r($final_array);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/1051388

***EDIT:-*** in case of empty string apply checks

```
<?php

$string = '';

if(strlen(trim(trim($string,',')))!== 0){

    $exploded_array = explode(',',$string);

    $final_array = array_chunk(array_filter($exploded_array) ,4);

    print_r($final_array);
    echo count($final_array);
    echo sizeof($final_array);
}else{
    echo "string is empty";
}
```

Reference:-

[trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

[strlen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)

[array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: Thanks you very much, I learn a lot from you answer and you explanation! Can you see the edit below?

Comment: @John  check my edited solution. I made it more correct logically

Answer (score 3):

1. Use `explode()` to convert string into array
2. Use `array_chunk()` to slice array to small chunks/array

Try this way:

```
$val = "234,153,25,25,85,36,40,40,188,155,60,60";
$strToArr = explode(",", $val);
$result = array_chunk($strToArr, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the snippet,

```
<?php
$temp   = explode(",", "234,153,25,25,85,36,40,40,188,155,60,60");
$j      = $i      = 0;
$result = [];
foreach ($temp as $piece) {
    if (($i++ % 4) == 0) {
        $j++;
    }
    $result[$j][] = $piece;
}
print_r($result);
```

Here is working [code](https://eval.in/1051396).

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = '234,153,25,25,85,36,40,40,188,155,60,60';
$b = explode(',',$a);
$c = array_chunk($b,4);
print_r($c);
```

Answer (score 1):

**First** you should used [explode PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function on the basis of `,`

**Second** you should used [array_chunk PHP Manual](http://php.net/array_chunk)  function

You can see the output [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0297c59c3d0d7d1addc0060c84c85e6ce7f1d057)

```
$a='234,153,25,25,85,36,40,40,188,155,60,60';
$array=explode(",",$a);
$b=array_chunk($array, 4);
print_r($b);
```

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation, please see the edit of the question.

Answer (score 0):

here is quick and dirty solution, but easy to understand IMHO.

```
<?php

$var = '234,153,25,25,85,36,40,40,188,155,60,60,20';
// Split array by ,
$ones = explode(',', $var);

$finalArray = [];

$i = 0;
// Iterate every 4
while ($i < count($ones)) {
    $j = 0;
    $a = [];
    // Iterate every one of four
    while ($j < 4) {
        if (array_key_exists($i + $j, $ones)) {
            //if exists, add to temp array
            $a[] = $ones[$i + $j];
        }
        $j++;
    }
    // Build string from array by implode and add to final array
    $finalArray[] = implode(',', $a);
    $i+=4;
}

var_dump($finalArray);
```

Comment: I'll take `array_chunk` any day over this, thankyouverymuch. ;-)

Comment: May be your logic is correct (as i am not tested it), but this is too much code for a simple task. If you can achieve something with pre-defined functions easily, always use them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$x = '234,153,25,25,85,36,40,40,188,155,60,60';
        $tmp = explode(",", $x);
        $array = [];
        $i = 0;
        $j = 0;
        $c = '';
        foreach($tmp as $key => $piece) {
            if($i != 0){
                $c .= ','.$piece; 
            }else{
                $c .= $piece; 
            }
            $i++;
            if($i == 3){
                $i = 0;
                $array[] = $c;
                $c = '';
            }
            $j++;
        }
```